# Convexity of the set of symmetric forms whose sum of k smallest eigenvalues is nonnegative

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an $n(<\infty)$ dimensional real vector space. Let
\begin{array}{l}
W:=\left\{\sigma\in V^\ast\otimes V^\ast\ |\ \sigma\text{ is a symmetric form on }V\right\}\oplus\left\{\tau\in V\otimes V\ |\ \tau\text{ is a symmetric form on }V^\ast\right\}\\
U:=\{\sigma\oplus\tau\in W\ |\ \tau\text{ is positive definite}\}. 
\end{array}
For each positive definite form $\tau\in V\otimes V$ on $V^\ast$, there is the inner product $\tau'\in V^\ast\otimes V^\ast$ on $V$ introduced from $\tau$ by identifying $V$ and $V^\ast$ using the inner product $\tau$ and Riesz's representation. 
For each $\sigma\oplus\tau\in U$ the linear transform $\tau\stackrel{\text{c}}\otimes\sigma$ on $V$ is symmetric with respect to the inner product $\tau'$, where "$\ ^{\text{c}}$" denotes the contraction of tensor. Hence their eigenvalues are real. We denote the $j$th smallest eigenvalue of it by $\lambda_j(\sigma\oplus\tau)$ $(j=1,\cdots,n)$.

Then is the set
\begin{array}{l}
X:=\left\{\sigma\oplus\tau\in U\ |\ \sum_{j=1}^k\lambda_j(\sigma\oplus\tau)\geq0\right\}\subset W
\end{array}
convex? ($k=1,\cdots,n$)

Thank you.